# Rolling back the trunk then branching

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

One of our developers added new functionality to the trunk rather than creating a branch. We're currently at revision 3966 as the HEAD. Work on that feature started at 3875 exclusively. Using TortoiseSVN, what's the best way to accomplish the following?

1. Rollback trunk to 3875.
2. Create branch from revisions 3876-3966
3. When finished with development of that feature, reintegrate back into the trunk

Can this best be accomplished by doing the following via TortoiseSVN?

1. Do an Update to Revision on the trunk's working copy and go back to 3875, commit those changes.
2. Inside of the Repo Browser, right click on the 3966 revision and create a branch

...or is there some other way?

Our process typically works like this:

1. Trunk is only for minor/single bug fixes and integrated branches
2. Branches are for features and/or sprints consisting of bug fixes that will have to be reviewed prior to integration into the trunk
3. Once branch is complete and QA'ed/reviewed, it's integrated into the trunk.
4. Once sprint of bug fixes is QA'ed/reviewed, it's integrated into the trunk.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do a reverse merge. http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch04s04.html#svn-ch-4-sect-4.2

I would just create a branch from trunk now, reverse merge trunk, and then merge the new branch into trunk.

Answer (score 0):

While @j-set is right in common, I want to disagree with him in details: I prefer to see unchanged (not collapsed) revision history, only change "mount point" of revisions-must-be-in branch

I order to get it

1. Using Repo-browser|Log create branch from revision 3875, which must be starting point of branch (f.e FEATURE-X) (if `svn diff -c 3875` will confirms changes in this revision as feature-related) and have two URLs in repo, used later (repo/trunk and repo/branches/FEATURE-X)
   [image: Repo-Browser log]
2. Checkout trunk into new temporary WC at revision REV+1 (3876)
3. Switch to repo/branches/FEATURE-X
4. Commit, repeating log-message from original revision (`svn log repo/trunk -r 3876-3966` for help)
5. Switch back to repo/trunk
6. Update to next revision in history
7. Return to step 3, while r3966 is not processed
8. When all branch-related revisions will be cloned to branch - reverse-merge transferred revisions from trunk and kill temporary WC